# picture in enumerate item with floating text

Tags: floats, diagrams, enumerate

I have a list with some text items and I want to add a picture to one of the items, so that the text of that item is floating to the left of the picture.

If I use wrapfigure my picture gets placed at the bottom of the page which is not what I want.

This is my tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\blindtext
\item
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.8cm}
\rule{5.8cm}{3.2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the `picins` package so can't see what you're trying to achieve but, omitting that and protecting the wrapfigure with its wrapping text inside a minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\blindtext
\begin{minipage}[t]{11.3cm}
\item
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.8cm}
\rule{5.8cm}{3.2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\item\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I'd be interested to know if that's anything like what you wanted and, perhaps from others, whether there is a better way (given a few more minutes I'd at least want to replace the hard size in the minipage definition with one based on settings from the page settings).

Comment: I'm sorry, I had tried with picins package before and forgot to remove the line for the minimal example. Your solution is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A little bit dirty solution. Maybe somebody can improve this. With the package `cutwin` I get the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,cutwin}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\mbox{\llap{\rule{3cm}{1pt}\hspace*{-1cm}}}\blindtext
\item\mbox{\llap{\rule{3cm}{1pt}\hspace*{-1cm}}}\relax
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\vskip-.85\ht\strutbox
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.8cm}
\rule{5.8cm}{3.2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item\mbox{\llap{\rule{3cm}{1pt}\hspace*{-1cm}}}\blindtext
\item\mbox{\llap{\rule{3cm}{1pt}\hspace*{-1cm}}}%
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\centering\rule{5.8cm}{3.2cm}}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\vskip-.9\ht\strutbox
\opencutright%
\begin{cutout}{2}{0.4\linewidth}{0pt}{10}
     \blindtext
\end{cutout}%
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works similar to the solution of mas, I think, but it draws some lines under the numbers of the list?

Comment: @Dennis: The lines are added manually by `\rule` to demonstrate the correct hight

Comment: Okay, I was a bit confused about them. Thanks for your help!